# ui-sref not working on ionicview, but works on browser, device and emulator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I use ionic for developing an application. There are lots of links and they all work fine. Only in a specific list, the links are not working just in ionicview. The html is:

```
    <ion-list class="indexed-list">
        <ion-item
            class="item item-avatar"
            ng-repeat="item in categoriesEntity"
            ui-sref="app.entityListSubCategory({subCategoryId: item.id})"
        >
            <img src="img/ionic.png">
            <h2 ng-bind="item.name"></h2>
            <span
                class="header assertive"
                ng-if="item.name.substr(0, 1) !== categoriesEntity[$index - 1].name.substr(0, 1)"
                ng-bind="item.name.substr(0, 1)"
            ></span>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-list>
```

I works fine in browser, emulator and device. I tried to replace `ui-sref` by `ng-click="alert('hello')"` and it was working. I also tried to move/copy `ui-sref` to `img` and `h2` tags but they wasn't working, too. I also tried replacing `ui-sref` by `ng-click` and using `$state` service to change route, but it was not working, too.

I log my JS errors to server. No JS errors occur when I tap on `ion-item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because I wrote a slash before the template name in ui-router :-(

Answer (score 0):

May be you haven't closed `<ion-item>` and `<ion-list>` is closed twice?

Comment: I was so surprised when I saw your answer but also happy that it's a really easy solution but I tried it and didn't work. Anyway, I'm installing a htmllint thing :-)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker so I can check what is wrong?

Comment: The problem occurs only in ionic view, not in browser or device.